# Should I use a bit mask when truncating uint64_t to uint8_t[i]?

Tags: c++, arrays, int, type-conversion, bit-manipulation

If I have a large int, say a uint64_t, and an array of uint8_t, e.g.:

```cpp
uint64_t large = 12345678901234567890;
uint8_t small[5];
```

and I want to copy the 8 least significant bits of the `uint64_t` into an element of the array of `uint8_t`, is it safe to just use:

```cpp
small[3] = large;
```

or should I use a bit-mask:

```cpp
small[3] = large & 255;
```

i.e. Is there any situation where the rest of the large int may somehow overflow into the other elements of the array?

Comment: It's perfectly safe.  Some compilers give a warning (IMHO this is a bogus warning since the code is correct) so there is no harm in using a mask. You could use `static_cast<uint8_t>(large);` perhaps, if you want to document the intent.

Comment: I'd remove the array from "small", as it serves no purpose on this question.

Comment: @xvan Actually the array was what made me worry. With a single uint8_t, I'd write `small = large` without hesitation.

Comment: The (large & 255) does have the beneficial effect of making it very clear to the human reader that you really did mean to throw away all but the lowest 8 bits, and didn't just accidentally fail to notice that your were assigning a 64-bit value to an 8-bit variable.  static_cast<uint8_t>(large & 0xFF) might be better still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *perfectly safe*:

```
small[3] = large;
```

and such a conversion is explicitly described in [conv.integral]:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

That is, these four statements all are guaranteed to end up with the same value in `small[3]`:

```
small[3] = large;
small[3] = large % 256;
small[3] = large & 255;
small[3] = static_cast<uint8_t>(large);
```

there's no functional reason to do the `%` or `&` or cast yourself, though if you want to anyway I would be surprised if the compiler didn't generate the same code for all four (gcc and clang do).

The one difference would be if you compile with something like `-Wconversion`, which would cause this to issue a warning (which can sometimes be beneficial). In that case, you'll want to do the cast.

Answer (score 5):

It will most certainly not cause data to be processed incorrectly. However, some compilers may generate a warning message.

There are two options to avoid these.

You can cast your variable:

```
(uint8_t)large
```

Or you can disable the warning:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4503)
```

I would suggest **casting** the variable, because hiding compiler warnings will potentially keep you from spotting actual problems and is therefore not best practice.

Comment: Mind you, casting, particularly C-style casts, is also going to hide warnings and errors. As long as the warning is only disabled for the scope where it's known to be safe, there is nothing morally superior about casting.

Comment: A `static_cast` might be more explicit, but for integral data types, C-style casts are sufficient.

Comment: I wasn't saying they wouldn't work, I was saying they could hide problems just as effectively as silencing warnings. A C-style cast can do much more dangerous things that `static_cast` and prevent the compiler from complaining, which is why it's so dangerous. It's not that it's bad in this case, but people whose first recourse is to shut up the compiler using casting end up being the ones who accidentally try to dereference `int`s as pointers and other terrible things. I'm specifically disputing your claim that a cast is somehow better than a localized warning suppression on principle.